# Gitlab notification

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm very new to gitlab and is assigned an issue to work. Email notification is not working while pushing, committing, or comment any issue in git lab.
I'm using gitlab CE 11.11.3 version in window server.

When any user is created in gitlab in that case user is getting mail from gitlab but in any other case it is not.

I have enabled the "email on push" service and while checking the logs, it is saying that "mail has been sent to emailID" but I'm not receiving any mail from gitlab.

Comment: Please do not ask urgent question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/7976758

Comment: Could you please tell what settings are configured by you ?